# Woody and Tinny Words

Tags: single-word-requests

I watched this Monty Python about describing words: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gwXJsWHupg

The characters give words different descriptions such as "woody" (gone, vacuum, caribou) or "tinny" (newspaper, litter-bin).

Is there a word to describe the emotion,  sound (not in a onomatopoeic sense), mood, or feeling of a word? The context I might use this word in is: "the XX of the word lugubrious is slimy."

I do not quite understand ideophones and that may be appropriate.

Comment: Remember, Python is _parody_. I believe the whole point of the sketch was to  make fun of  wine snobs and the like who attempt to assign possibly arbitrary words to highly subjective judgments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Timbre** [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/timber?show=1&t=1419560786)

> :  the quality given to a sound by its overtones: as
>
> a :  the resonance by which the ear recognizes and identifies a voiced speech sound
>
> b :  the quality of tone distinctive of a particular singing voice or musical instrument

This would be borrowing from music, but I believe it captures well the musical quality of words you're looking for.

Comment: I think OP is looking for a word which describes certain classes of words which have an emotional or categorical sameness. To me, the words **mortuary, cremation, undertaker** and **funeral home** share a certain gloominess.

Comment: This is the not quite what I was hoping for but the closest I think I'll get. Thanks

Comment: @IconDaemon Definition 'b' above is what I'm applying here. "the quality of [associations/connotations, etc.] distinctive of a particular [word or set of words]". If someone were to begin speaking to you about the timbre of a certain word, the concept wouldn't be particularly hard to grasp.

Comment: @user3235:  there are at least two types of reactions to a word.  Are you referring to the feeling one gets from the SOUND of a word, or the feeling one gets from the connotations or associations based on the MEANING of a word, or both simultaneously?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Primarily the sound. It is also likely that the meaning of a word informs the pronunciation of it and hence the sound.

Comment: Words coined in imitation of a sound (whoosh, grunt, hiss, thud) are called onomatopoieic. For a fun twist on interpreting words by sound as well as meaning, check out the Sesquiotica blog.

Answer (score 1):

This may have been a comedy sketch, but the characteristics of word sounds are something that people in the "funny-business" take very seriously. For example:

"What's that on my plate?" "It's a string bean" (Not funny)
"What's that on my plate?" "It's a pickle" (Funny)

(The *hard-c*, or "k" sound, is amusing, for some reason.)

"What's the matter?" "I have a cold" (Not funny)
"What's the matter?" "I have sinus congestion" (Funny)

(Consecutive "s" sounds also tickle the ear)

*Timbre* is a good descriptor, but it seems to refer more to the vowel sounds. You could simply use "tone".